# Unknown comparison

Tags: assembly, x86, decompilation, c

I'm trying to decompile some singleplayer code for a game (C++ on X86 architecture Linux). I do this with the help of some already available source code, a file (compiled on linux) with debug information and Ida Pro (Mainly only using pseudo-c code conversion). So far everything has been going good up until now. There is a comparison going on which I can't make any sense of.

Below is a part of the function that is the problem:

```
if (v28)
{
    health_1 = Commands->Get_Health(obj);
    this->field_1C = health_1;
    v14 = health_1 < 0.0;
    v15 = 0;
    v16 = health_1 == 0.0;
    if ((HIBYTE(v13) & 0x45) == 64)
        v17 = this->field_20 - this->field_1C + this->field_24;
    else
        v17 = this->field_20 - this->field_1C;
    v18 = v17;
    v19 = ScriptImpClass::Get_Float_Parameter(&this->base, "Damage_multiplier") * v18;
    this->field_24 = v19 + this->field_24;
    v20 = this->field_20 - v19;
    Commands->Set_Health(obj, v20);
    this->field_20 = Commands->Get_Health(obj);
    this->field_1C = Commands->Get_Health(obj);
}
```

There is the following comparison:

```
if ((HIBYTE(v13) & 0x45) == 64)
```

I just cannot figure out what is being checked here. I believe that the if (v28) statement starts at address .text:084D16BF. Below is the complete bytecode of the function and the structure layout of M00_Damage_Modifier_DME

```
00000000 GameObjObserverClass struc; (sizeof = 0x8, mappedto_2746); XREF: ScriptClass / r
00000000 vPtr            dd ? ; offset
00000004 ID              dd ?
00000008 GameObjObserverClass ends

00000000 ScriptClass     struc; (sizeof = 0x8, mappedto_2767); XREF: ScriptImpClass / r
00000000 base            GameObjObserverClass ?
00000008 ScriptClass     ends

00000000 ScriptImpClass  struc; (sizeof = 0x1C, mappedto_2754)
00000000; XREF: _ZN17M08_Prison_Patrol7CreatedEP17ScriptableGameObj / r
00000000; _ZN10M08_Sniper7CreatedEP17ScriptableGameObj / r ...
00000000 base            ScriptClass ?
00000008 mOwner          dd ? ; offset
0000000C mArgC           dd ?
00000010 mArgV           dd ? ; offset
00000014 mFactory        dd ? ; offset
00000018 AutoVariableList dd ? ; offset
0000001C ScriptImpClass  ends

00000000 M00_Damage_Modifier_DME struc; (sizeof = 0x3C, mappedto_2798)
00000000 base            ScriptImpClass ?
0000001C field_1C        dd ?
00000020 field_20        dd ?
00000024 field_24        dd ?
00000028 killableByStar  dd ?
0000002C killableByNotStar dd ?
00000030 starModifier    dd ?
00000034 notStarModifier dd ?
00000038 enabled         db ?
00000039 pad_01          db ?
0000003A pad_02          db ?
0000003B pad_03          db ?
0000003C M00_Damage_Modifier_DME ends

.text:084D1582; void __cdecl M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(M00_Damage_Modifier_DME *this, ScriptableGameObj *obj, ScriptableGameObj *damager, float amount)
.text:084D1582                 public _ZN23M00_Damage_Modifier_DME7DamagedEP17ScriptableGameObjS1_f; weak
.text:084D1582 _ZN23M00_Damage_Modifier_DME7DamagedEP17ScriptableGameObjS1_f proc near
.text:084D1582; DATA XREF : .data : 08659468o
.text:084D1582
.text:084D1582 var_5C = dword ptr - 5Ch
.text:084D1582 var_58 = dword ptr - 58h
.text:084D1582 var_43 = byte ptr - 43h
.text:084D1582 var_42 = byte ptr - 42h
.text:084D1582 var_41 = byte ptr - 41h
.text:084D1582 var_40 = dword ptr - 40h
.text:084D1582 pos_1 = Vector3 ptr - 3Ch
.text:084D1582 pos = Vector3 ptr - 2Ch
.text:084D1582 this = dword ptr  4
.text:084D1582 obj = dword ptr  8
.text:084D1582 damager = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:084D1582 amount = dword ptr  10h
.text:084D1582
.text:084D1582                 push    ebp
.text:084D1583                 push    edi
.text:084D1584                 push    esi
.text:084D1585                 push    ebx
.text:084D1586                 sub     esp, 3Ch
.text:084D1589                 mov     edi, [esp + 4Ch + this]
.text:084D158D                 mov     ebp, [esp + 4Ch + obj]
.text:084D1591                 cmp     byte ptr[edi + 38h], 0
.text:084D1595                 jz      loc_84D184B
.text:084D159B                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_41], 0
.text:084D15A0                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 30h], 0
.text:084D15A4                 jnz     short loc_84D15DD
.text:084D15A6                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D15A9                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D15AF                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos]
.text:084D15B3                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D15B6                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D15B8                 push    edi
.text:084D15B9                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D15BC                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D15BF                 push    eax
.text:084D15C0                 push    ebx
.text:084D15C1                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D15C4                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D15C7                 push    ebx
.text:084D15C8                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D15CE                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D15D1                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D15D5                 jnz     short loc_84D15DD
.text:084D15D7                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 28h], 0
.text:084D15DB                 jnz     short loc_84D161A
.text:084D15DD
.text:084D15DD loc_84D15DD : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 22j
.text:084D15DD; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 53j
.text:084D15DD                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 34h], 0
.text:084D15E1                 jnz     short loc_84D161F
.text:084D15E3                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D15E6                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D15EC                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos_1]
.text:084D15F0                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D15F3                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D15F5                 push    edi
.text:084D15F6                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D15F9                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D15FC                 push    eax
.text:084D15FD                 push    ebx
.text:084D15FE                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D1601                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D1604                 push    ebx
.text:084D1605                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D160B                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D160E                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D1612                 jz      short loc_84D161F
.text:084D1614                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 2Ch], 0
.text:084D1618                 jz      short loc_84D161F
.text:084D161A
.text:084D161A loc_84D161A : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 59j
.text:084D161A                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_41], 1
.text:084D161F
.text:084D161F loc_84D161F : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 5Fj
.text:084D161F; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 90j ...
.text:084D161F                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + var_41], 0
.text:084D1624                 jz      short loc_84D163B
.text:084D1626                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D1629                 push    ebp
.text:084D162A                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D162F                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D1635                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D1638                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D163B
.text:084D163B loc_84D163B : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + A2j
.text:084D163B                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_42], 0
.text:084D1640                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 30h], 0
.text:084D1644                 jz      short loc_84D167D
.text:084D1646                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D1649                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D164F                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos_1]
.text:084D1653                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D1656                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D1658                 push    edi
.text:084D1659                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D165C                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D165F                 push    eax
.text:084D1660                 push    ebx
.text:084D1661                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D1664                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D1667                 push    ebx
.text:084D1668                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D166E                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D1671                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D1675                 jnz     short loc_84D167D
.text:084D1677                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 28h], 0
.text:084D167B                 jnz     short loc_84D16BA
.text:084D167D
.text:084D167D loc_84D167D : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + C2j
.text:084D167D; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + F3j
.text:084D167D                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 34h], 0
.text:084D1681                 jz      short loc_84D16BF
.text:084D1683                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D1686                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D168C                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos]
.text:084D1690                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D1693                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D1695                 push    edi
.text:084D1696                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D1699                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D169C                 push    eax
.text:084D169D                 push    ebx
.text:084D169E                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D16A1                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D16A4                 push    ebx
.text:084D16A5                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D16AB                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D16AE                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D16B2                 jz      short loc_84D16BF
.text:084D16B4                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 2Ch], 0
.text:084D16B8                 jz      short loc_84D16BF
.text:084D16BA
.text:084D16BA loc_84D16BA : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + F9j
.text:084D16BA                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_42], 1
.text:084D16BF
.text:084D16BF loc_84D16BF : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + FFj
.text:084D16BF; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 130j ...
.text:084D16BF                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + var_42], 0
.text:084D16C4                 jz      loc_84D1758
.text:084D16CA                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D16CD                 push    ebp
.text:084D16CE                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D16D3                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D16D9                 fst     dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D16DC                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D16DF                 fldz
.text:084D16E1                 fxch    st(1)
.text:084D16E3                 fucompp
.text:084D16E5                 fnstsw  ax
.text:084D16E7                 and     ah, 45h
.text:084D16EA                 xor     ah, 40h
.text:084D16ED                 jnz     short loc_84D16FA
.text:084D16EF                 fld     dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D16F2                 fsub    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D16F5                 fadd    dword ptr[edi + 24h]
.text:084D16F8                 jmp     short loc_84D1700
.text:084D16FA; -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -
.text:084D16FA
.text:084D16FA loc_84D16FA : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 16Bj
.text:084D16FA                 fld     dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D16FD                 fsub    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D1700
.text:084D1700 loc_84D1700 : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 176j
.text:084D1700                 fstp[esp + 4Ch + var_40]
.text:084D1704                 sub     esp, 8
.text:084D1707                 push    offset aDamage_multi_0; "Damage_multiplier"
.text:084D170C                 push    edi; this
.text:084D170D                 call    _ZN14ScriptImpClass19Get_Float_ParameterEPKc; ScriptImpClass::Get_Float_Parameter(char const*)
.text:084D1712                 fmul[esp + 5Ch + var_40]
.text:084D1716                 fld     st
.text:084D1718                 fadd    dword ptr[edi + 24h]
.text:084D171B                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 24h]
.text:084D171E                 add     esp, 4
.text:084D1721                 fsubr   dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D1724                 fstp[esp + 58h + var_58]
.text:084D1727                 push    ebp
.text:084D1728                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D172D                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0E4h]
.text:084D1733                 mov[esp + 5Ch + var_5C], ebp
.text:084D1736                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D173B                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D1741                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D1744                 mov[esp + 5Ch + var_5C], ebp
.text:084D1747                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D174C                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D1752                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D1755                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D1758
.text:084D1758 loc_84D1758 : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 142j
.text:084D1758                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_43], 0
.text:084D175D                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 30h], 0
.text:084D1761                 jz      short loc_84D179A
.text:084D1763                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D1766                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D176C                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos_1]
.text:084D1770                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D1773                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D1775                 push    edi
.text:084D1776                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D1779                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D177C                 push    eax
.text:084D177D                 push    ebx
.text:084D177E                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D1781                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D1784                 push    ebx
.text:084D1785                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D178B                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D178E                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D1792                 jnz     short loc_84D179A
.text:084D1794                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 28h], 0
.text:084D1798                 jz      short loc_84D17D7
.text:084D179A
.text:084D179A loc_84D179A : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 1DFj
.text:084D179A; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 210j
.text:084D179A                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 34h], 0
.text:084D179E                 jz      short loc_84D17DC
.text:084D17A0                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D17A3                 mov     esi, Commands
.text:084D17A9                 lea     ebx, [esp + 58h + pos]
.text:084D17AD                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:084D17B0                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:084D17B2                 push    edi
.text:084D17B3                 call    dword ptr[eax + 48h]
.text:084D17B6                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D17B9                 push    eax
.text:084D17BA                 push    ebx
.text:084D17BB                 call    dword ptr[esi + 40h]
.text:084D17BE                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D17C1                 push    ebx
.text:084D17C2                 call    dword ptr[esi + 110h]
.text:084D17C8                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D17CB                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + damager], eax
.text:084D17CF                 jz      short loc_84D17DC
.text:084D17D1                 cmp     dword ptr[edi + 2Ch], 0
.text:084D17D5                 jnz     short loc_84D17DC
.text:084D17D7
.text:084D17D7 loc_84D17D7 : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 216j
.text:084D17D7                 mov[esp + 4Ch + var_43], 1
.text:084D17DC
.text:084D17DC loc_84D17DC : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 21Cj
.text:084D17DC; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 24Dj ...
.text:084D17DC                 cmp[esp + 4Ch + var_43], 0
.text:084D17E1                 jz      short loc_84D184B
.text:084D17E3                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:084D17E6                 push    ebp
.text:084D17E7                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D17EC                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D17F2                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D17F5                 add     esp, 8
.text:084D17F8                 fld     dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D17FB                 fsub    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D17FE                 fstp[esp + 54h + var_40]
.text:084D1802                 push    offset aDamage_multi_0; "Damage_multiplier"
.text:084D1807                 push    edi; this
.text:084D1808                 call    _ZN14ScriptImpClass19Get_Float_ParameterEPKc; ScriptImpClass::Get_Float_Parameter(char const*)
.text:084D180D                 fmul[esp + 5Ch + var_40]
.text:084D1811                 add     esp, 4
.text:084D1814                 fsubr   dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D1817                 fstp[esp + 58h + var_58]
.text:084D181A                 push    ebp
.text:084D181B                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D1820                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0E4h]
.text:084D1826                 mov[esp + 5Ch + var_5C], ebp
.text:084D1829                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D182E                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D1834                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 20h]
.text:084D1837                 mov[esp + 5Ch + var_5C], ebp
.text:084D183A                 mov     eax, Commands
.text:084D183F                 call    dword ptr[eax + 0DCh]
.text:084D1845                 fstp    dword ptr[edi + 1Ch]
.text:084D1848                 add     esp, 10h
.text:084D184B
.text:084D184B loc_84D184B : ; CODE XREF : M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 13j
.text:084D184B; M00_Damage_Modifier_DME::Damaged(ScriptableGameObj *, ScriptableGameObj *, float) + 25Fj
.text:084D184B                 add     esp, 3Ch
.text:084D184E                 pop     ebx
.text:084D184F                 pop     esi
.text:084D1850                 pop     edi
.text:084D1851                 pop     ebp
.text:084D1852                 retn
.text:084D1852 _ZN23M00_Damage_Modifier_DME7DamagedEP17ScriptableGameObjS1_f endp
.text:084D1852
.text:084D1852; -------------------------------------------------------------------------- -
```

I tried looking up the opcodes at that area, but it didn't help me solve it either. I'm a complete noob when it comes to assembly.

Comment: hibyte means it is checking ax,or bx or cxxxxx etc look for and reg ,const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in question seems to correspond to this sequence:

```
.text:084D16DF                 fldz
.text:084D16E1                 fxch    st(1)
.text:084D16E3                 fucompp
.text:084D16E5                 fnstsw  ax
.text:084D16E7                 and     ah, 45h
.text:084D16EA                 xor     ah, 40h
```

This performs comparison of the FPU stack values, then copies FPU flags to `ax` and checks its value (probably to determine the result of comparison). Since the Hex-Rays decompiler supports FPU instructions (including comparisons) [since at least version 1.1](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/v11_vs_v10.shtml#5), you either have a too old version or have hit on a bug. Try to update to the latest version or [report it](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/failures.shtml#report) if it's still present.

Comment: Where I am working I cannot upgrade IDA. Would you happen to know how this piece of code would translate to c code? If not, I thank you for your help and will accept your answer anyway. Edit: I cant check the version right now but I will Asap. Also I did find that out what you said (the opcodes) but I still dont really know how that would translate to C.

Comment: I believe I have version 6.8 of IDA. So I guess its a bug

Comment: 6.8 is not the latest (it was released in 2015)

Comment: I've found out what the comparison is. It checks if health_1 == 0. I've found a similar line somewhere else, where I was able to identify it.